# about perfect matching

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, matching-theory

A perfect matching is a matching that matches all vertices of the graph.

> find the number of perfect matching of following graph :

[image]

i think we have two general case:

case 1 perfect matchings in yellow graph as below :

[image]

in this case we have only two perfect matchings in any yellow graph so we have $2^4$ perfect matchings

[image]

case 2 perfect matchings in white graphs as above. with similar way we have $2^4$ perfect matchings. so we have $2^4+2^4=32$ perfect matchings. is my answer true ?

Comment: No. You have double counted the matching | | | | | | | | | and are missing some matchings such as | = | = | = .

Comment: Relate your question to the one about tiling a $1\times n$ grid with dominoes and monominos.  There is a [famous recurrence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) that appears in the standard solution.